# changing keys of a multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array as shown below. How do I change the keys that start with "id of"?

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id of ten] => 1871
        [name] => bob
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id of nine hundred thousand] => 12581
        [name] => barney        
    )

)
```

Normally, you'd do something like:

```
foreach ( $array as $k=>$v )
{
  $array[$k] ['id'] = $array[$k] ['old'];
  unset($array[$k]['old']);
}
```

In my case, the key changes dynamically (there are thousands of keys in my multidimensional array and they are random but they will always start w/ "id of...")

thx!

Comment: you want to change meaning you don't want it to display?

Comment: I want to change the name of the key. I do not want to change the value

Comment: you just want id not id of nine hundred thousand? as thought you key is changing dynamically where is the code where is changing it dynamically you have to show some more code I think you have a dynamic variable next to the id which is echoing or printing this.

Comment: What is it you're ultimately trying to do? I'm not following the "key changes dynamically" part; is the array provided to you as-is? Can you change the field name in the query you're using (assuming that's what it is)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 'id of' key is always the first element of the array, you can use the following:

```
foreach ($input as &$value)
{
  $value['key'] = reset($value);
  $key = key($value);
  unset($value[$key]);
}
```

Otherwise, the following worked for me:

```
foreach ($input as &$value)
{
  foreach ($value as $key=>$el) {
    if (substr($key, 0, 5) == 'id of') {
      $value['key'] = $el;
      unset($value[$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

In both cases you can change `$value['key']` to whatever you want the new key to be.

Comment: see second commentary to question from OP

Comment: @OZ_ I think I'm understanding it correctly... If he wants to change the key name, he can use `$value['desired_key']` Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering if this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array(
        "id of one" => 434,
        "name" => "bob"
    ),
    array(
        "id of two" => 9323,
        "name" => "ted"
    )
);

$c_array = count($array);

for ($i = 0; $i < $c_array; $i++)
{
    foreach ($array[$i] as $key => $value)
    {
        if (substr($key, 0, 5) == 'id of') {
            $array[$i][substr($key, 6)] = $value;
            unset($array[$i][$key]);
        }
    }
}

print_r($array);

?>
```

NOTE: Includes use of `substr()` instead of `strpos()`. See Gumbo's comment below.

https://ideone.com/xBV5L

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => bob
            [one] => 434
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => ted
            [two] => 9323
        )

)
```

Comment: Better use `substr` instead of `strpos`.

Comment: @Gumbo - Not quite following your comment. You mean replace the usage of strpos with substr?

Comment: @OZ_: Yes. You don’t need to search the whole string if you just have to look at the first 6 characters.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: I said the first six characters and not the first five.

Comment: @Gumbo - I don't think that matters, I'll let the OP decide.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: But I hope at least you know the difference.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is very clean. Array_shift, does two things at once: returns first element (which has the id), and deletes it from the array, so you can directly assign it to the $new_array at 'id'

```
$new_arr=array();
foreach ( $array as $arr)
{
  $new_arr[array_shift($arr)] = $arr;
}
```